# Change css style with if statements

Tags: angularjs

Atm i have table that display what status my member has. Is it possible to do like,
If member status = Bronze -> td background = bronze?
Im sorry if im unclear about the problem, But i want to change color of td background depending on what status the member has.
Any suggestion how i can do it?

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
            app.filter('status', function () {
                return function (input) {
                    var statu = input;
                    switch (input) {
                        case 10:
                            statu = 'Bronze';
                            break;
                        case 20:
                            statu = 'Silver';

                            break;
                        case 30:
                            statu = 'Gold';
                            break;
                        case 40:
                            statu = 'Elite';
                            break;
                    }
                    return statu;

                };
            });
```

Comment: You can use `ng-style` or `ng-class`, keep a map of status-code/class and use it. Can you show your html as well for a better picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

For example:

```
.bronze {
  background-color: red;
}
.silver{
  background-color: gray;
}


$scope.items = [
   {color: 'bronze'},
   {color: 'silver'}
];


<div ng-repeat="item in items"
     ng-class="{bronze: item.color == 'bronze', silver: item.color == 'silver'}">
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just parse `item.color` in this example? eg: `class="{{item.color}}"`

Comment: @rlecaro2 No, because there is no such css color as "bronze" :P 
But I agree with you, that it's easier :)

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally change a class I suggest `ng-class`

Ex:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function() {
    $scope.show = false;  

    if(condiiton) {
        $scope.show = true;
    }

});
```

And augment your HTML like so:

```
<input ng-class="{ show: classname }">
```

Read more here if this example doesn't suffice: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

in view pass the member status to `changeBgColor` function inside the controller

```
<td ng-style="changeBgColor(member.status)">
```

In controller,

```
$scope.changeBgColor = function(status) {
    var statu = status;
    switch (status) {
        case 10:
            statu = 'Bronze';
            break;
        case 20:
            statu = 'Silver';
            break;
        case 30:
            statu = 'Gold';
            break;
        case 40:
            statu = 'Elite';
            break;
      }
      return {'background-color': statu};
}
```